DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT fails only for clob with special character
I am using Oracle database 19.4 standard edition
This works
select DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT((chr(2)) ) from dual;

but when converting to clob it fails
select DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(to_clob(chr(2)) ) from dual

ORA-64451: Conversion of special character to escaped character failed.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 29
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 301
ORA-06512: at line 1

Why is this the case?

This looks like a bug, so you probably need to raise a service request with Oracle. There is a reference note for that error (doc ID 2010807.1) but it doesn't seem to cover this issue.
